# Safari 5 button bug?

Tags: button, safari

I've noticed a bug in Safari 5.0.3 with the button-element. Safari is wrapping the button in a space like margin or padding. [The bug can be seen here](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/nokia-2610-phone.html).

How can I fix that? Even "-webkit-border-fit:lines; -webkit-margin-collapse: discard or collapse" didn't help. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: which button in that URL is the one we should be looking at?

Comment: The Bug touches every button-element as I said already. For example the "Add to Cart" button or the search button. In every other browser there is no padding or margin arround the buttons.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing on the page? It's the same for me in Chrome, FF and Safari 5.0.3

Comment: [Here is it](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/341/compareb.png/) On the Picture you can see the 1px margin-top and the small margin-left. It's just a small difference but it's still visible